How do I join two data frames on a nested array attribute
I have two dataframes created from ingestion json data w/ the below schemas

provider:

{
    npi: "..."
    name: "..."
    location: {
        address: "...",
        insurances: ["...", "..."],
        ...
    },
    ...
}

insurance:

{
    id: ...,
    ...
}

I would like to join provider df on insurance df where provider.location.insurances contains insurance.id, and add matching insurances as a new array field insurances. Is this possible?
So the resulting data structure would be something like this:
{
    npi: "..."
    name: "..."
    location: {
        address: "...",
        insurances: [123, ...],
        ...
    },
    insurances: [{id: 123, ...}, ...]
}


I was able to accomplish this with the below code, but please let me know if you see a more memory optimized way to do this, thanks.
insuranceDF = insuranceDF.withColumn("insurance", F.struct("uuid", "carrier_name"))

joinDF = providerDF.join(insuranceDF, F.expr("array_contains(location.insurances, uuid)")).groupBy("npi", "location").agg(F.collect_list("insurance"))


Try

# Join provider and insurance data
joined_data = exploded_providers.join(insurances, exploded_providers.insurance == insurances.id)
